# Start macro by double click for multiple cell range

Tags: vba, excel

Im trying to start a macro when someone double-clicks a certain range of cells. The compleet sub I got now is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, cancel As Boolean)

If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("F5")) Is Nothing Then
cancel = True
Dim GoogleMapsCheckLink As String
GoogleMapsCheckLink = "https://www.google.nl/maps/place/" + Range("F5").Value + " " + Range("F6").Value + " " + Range("F7").Value
ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink GoogleMapsCheckLink
GoogleMapsCheckYN.Show
End If


If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("B52, B61, D52, D61")) Is Nothing Then
    cancel = True
    macro


End If

End Sub
```

But whenever I select one of the cells e.g. B52, B61, D52 or D61 I get a compile error with the message:

> Compile error:
>
> Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment

The word Range is highlighted.

My question is of course what am I doing wrong currently?

**EDIT:**

After changing Range to

```
Range("B52, B61, D52, D61")
```

I get another error:

> Run-time error '1004':
>
> Method ' Range' of object'_Worksheet' failed

Btw I also got other macros that are being activated through double clicking a certain cell value and those do work. The error only occurs when I got multiple cells as range...

Comment: Maurice, if you edit the question, edit the resulting error too please!

Comment: You say the error occurs when you *select* the cell? Did you mean when you double-click?

Comment: So? Any luck with anything?

Comment: added the complete sub now in my orignal post. So when I double click the cell F5 the macro that should be called works. But when I double click B52, B61, D52, D61 I get the error msg. (the macro that is being called upon works so I guess that isnt the problem)

Comment: I have just copy-pasted your code into an empty workbook, and it works. You said the error occurred at the `If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("B52, B61, D52, D61"))` part, yes?  (I have let it run to the GrossDebt1 inputbox, and no errors to that point.) Try putting it in a different workbook. I really have no idea here, that should work.

Comment: I still get the same error even when I run the module in an other worksheet. The weird thing is, that it was working last week. But for some strange reason it is not working today...

Answer (score 0):

Change your range like this:

```
Range("B52, B61, D52, D61")
```

This is now a valid range reference in Excel. The Range method either accepts two references, and then refers to all the cells in between, or accepts a valid range name.

Comment: I just adjusted it and get the following error:

Run-time error '1004':
Method 'Range' of object'_Worksheet' failed

Comment: I think you mistyped something then.

Comment: Yeah, I have tested this, and it works. Don't just ctrl-c + ctrl-v the code, sometimes the quotation marks in VBA are different from the ones in the browser. Try manually changing the code.

Comment: Just did it and still getting the same error message. Btw I also got other macros that are being activated through double clicking a certain cell value and those do work. The error only occurs when I got multiple cells as range...

Comment: I'm baffled, the code totally works for me. Maybe your sheet is protected? Or someone cast a dark spell on you.

Comment: I added the complete sub now in my orignal post. So when I double click the cell F5 the macro that should be called works. But when I double click B52, B61, D52, D61 I get the error msg. (the macro that is being called upon works so I guess that isnt the problem)

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me, using Office 2010.

If the Targets are in Sheet1 then make sure the script is in the Sheet1 Module

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("B52, B61, D52, D61")) Is Nothing Then

        Cancel = True

        Worked = "Yes"

        'Calling Macro would go here
        Call SomeModule.SomeMarco

    Else

        Worked = "No"

    End If


    MsgBox Worked

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you put it in the proper sub? The double click event?

Comment: So, you found the same solution. :) For OP, it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: See update, I didnt see the Double-Clicj part of the question. But my update answer works perfectly. Just remember to reference the Module and Macro when calling it. Eg  Call Module1.Marco1

Comment: Please read the original problem again. For Maurice, Range("B52, B61, D52, D61") produces the error.

Comment: Yes, same for me, as we have already discussed... But not for Maurice.

Comment: It is still not working. I coppied the whole private sub now.

Comment: @Maurice did you paste it in the `Sheets1(Sheet1)` Project?

Comment: added the complete sub now in my orignal post. So when I double click the cell F5 the macro that should be called works. But when I double click B52, B61, D52, D61 I get the error msg. (the macro that is being called upon works so I guess that isnt the problem)

Comment: @Jean-PierreOosthuizen Yes Jean, the complete sub is in the correct worksheet project.